# how do I integrate x^4 using the integral definition?

Tags: calculus, integration

By definition I mean the definition of an integral, as in a limit of a Riemann sum. I'm teaching myself about integrals and I'm not sure how to solve this problem without running into issues. I know using the power rule that the answer is supposed to be 618.6, but im not sure how to do it the long way.

Here is my work so far:

"integrate $∫_2^5 x^4$ using the definition:"

$$∫_a^b f(x)\,dx)=∑_{i=1}^n f(x_i)Δx $$
$$Δx=(b-a)/n,\enspace
x_i=a+iΔx $$

a=2
b=5
Δx=<sup>3</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>
x<sub>i</sub>=2+<sup>3i</sup>⁄<sub>n</sub>
f(x<sub>i</sub>)=(2+<sup>3i</sup>⁄<sub>n</sub>)<sup>4</sup>
f(x<sub>i</sub>)=(16+(96i)⁄<sub>n</sub>+(216i<sup>2</sup>)⁄<sub>n<sup>2</sup>></sub>+(216i<sup>3</sup>)⁄<sub>n<sup>3</sup></sub>+(81i<sup>4</sup>)⁄<sub>n<sup>4</sup></sub>

∑<sup>n</sup><sub>i=1</sub>[3(16+96i+216i<sup>2</sup>+216i<sup>3</sup>+81i<sup>4</sup>)/n<sup>5</sup>]

∑<sup>n</sup><sub>i=1</sub>[48/n+288i/n<sup>2</sup>+648i<sup>2</sup>/n<sup>3</sup>+648i<sup>3</sup>/n<sup>4</sup>+243i<sup>4</sup>/n<sup>5</sup>

48/n∑<sup>n</sup>i=1 + 288/n^2∑<sup>n</sup>i=1 i + 648/n^3 ∑<sup>n</sup>i=1 i^2 + 648/n^4∑<sup>n</sup>i=1 i^3 + 243/n^5∑<sup>n</sup>i=1 i^4

48+(288/n^2)((n(n+1)/2)+(648/n^3)(n(n+1)(2n+1)/6)+(648/n^4)((n(n+1/2))^2+(243/n^5)(n(n+1)(2n+1)/6)^2

Comment: Where's the limit in your "derivation"? Anyways, this is not a good way to solve the problem. Have you seen the proof of the power rule?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: When you integrate the linear function $f(x)=x$ "the long way" you see that you need a formula for the sum of the first $n$ integers. (You end up deriving the formula for the area of a triangle.) To integrate $f(x)=x^2$ you need the formula for the sum of the first $n$ squares. And so on. Once you understand the principle you don't learn much by carrying out the details in individual cases like the one you ask about.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition we will have $\Delta x=\frac{3}{n}$ and $x^i=2+\frac{3}{n} i.$ So now we will deal with the expression:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n(2+\frac{3}{n} i)^4(\frac{3}{n})$$ After you have expanded the inside of the summation, dealt with the tedious algebra to simplify and applied the summation formulas for $i, i^2, i^3$ and $i^4$ you will have the following:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{3}{n}(16n+\frac{96}{n}(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})+\frac{216}{n^2}(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6})+\frac{216}{n^3}(\frac{1}{4}n^2(n+1)^2)+\frac{81}{n^4}(\frac{1}{30}n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1))$$ Which simplifies to:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{3}{10n^4}(2062n^4+3045n^3+1170n^2-27)$$ Which at last becomes:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}618.6+\frac{913.5}{n}+\frac{351}{n^2}-\frac{8.1}{n^4}=618.6$$ Which is the correct answer since as $n \to \infty $, the last $3$ terms all goes to $0$ and we're only left with the constant. Setting up the Riemann Integral is pretty easy if you understand the definition, the only tricky thing is the actual computation itself, it can get ridiculous when you're dealing with harder functions, this is obviously why we don't really use the definition when integrating a function but instead we have wonderful rules which allows us to skip all the horrible algebra/arithmetic, similarly to when we differentiate functions we don't use the formal definition of the derivative every time, we use power rule, chain rule etc.

Comment: You may want to use LaTeX/MathJax commands `\left` and `\right` to adjust parentheses size automatically to their content: see `(\frac {3+\frac 12}4)^2` → $(\frac {3+\frac 12}4)^2$ vs. `\left(\frac {3+\frac 12}4\right)^2` → $\left(\frac {3+\frac 12}4\right)^2$.